# How can I get the value of span within a list using vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript and am having a tough time getting the value inside of span within a list. In my example below I want `console.log()` to return the string value of **Active**.

Also, I know I can directly get it by using, but want to avoid this as I need to get to the specific list first and then get the attribute value of the span. So example below is not what I'm looking for.

```
var x = document.querySelector('.checkout-form__step-text').innerText;
```

I've tried the following, but am not having any luck:

```
var thisStep1 = document.querySelector('.checkout-form__step--active').getAttribute('span')
    console.log(thisStep1)
```

```html
<li class = 'checkout-form__step checkout-form__step--active'>
  <span class="checkout-form__step-text p3"> Active</span>
</li>
```

Comment: It is not clear why you cannot use the first code snippet. It's like you have your arrow lined up on the bullseye and you decide you need to bank it off the nearest building first...

Comment: Span is a `tagName`, not an attribute

Comment: @Taplar, Initially, I thought that the author needs the content of the `span`, but I added a second solution, using `tagName`.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov If the selector has `span` at the end, what's the point?  You already know what the tag name is.

Comment: @Taplar, the point is to get the tag name itself in text format. But now I'm confused.

Comment: Lol, again, you already know it.  You put it as text in the selector.  It's pointless.

Answer (score 2):

This should be your selector.

```
document.querySelector('.checkout-form__step--active span')
```

Please check the below snippet.

```js
const thisStep1 = document.querySelector('.checkout-form__step--active span');
console.log(thisStep1.innerHTML)
```

```html
<li class='checkout-form__step checkout-form__step--active'>
  <span class="checkout-form__step-text p3"> Active</span>
</li>
```

For examples on using selectors, some useful links are:

- [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Locating DOM elements using selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors)
- [Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors)
- [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: Thanks a ton for this Peter. Is there a document you can guide me to where I can understand what led you to put Span after the class name.

Comment: @zneedhelp yes one moment please.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a grave mistake. Selector `.checkout-form__step--active` does not contain the `span` attribute. And `span` is not an attribute, but a tag!

I have given two solutions. In the first solution, you get the **content** of the `span` tag, and in the second, you get the **name** of the `span` tag.

If I understand your question correctly, then you need to get the text of the `span` tag in the `console`. You can do it like this, using `innerText`, specifying the `span` tag in the selector when accessing. Like this:

```
('.checkout-form__step--active span')
```

```js
var thisStep1 = document.querySelector('.checkout-form__step--active span').innerText;

console.log(thisStep1);
```

```html
<li class = 'checkout-form__step checkout-form__step--active'>
  <span class="checkout-form__step-text p3"> Active</span>
</li>
```

This is where you get the tag name using `tagName`:

```js
var thisStep1 = document.querySelector('.checkout-form__step--active span').tagName;

console.log(thisStep1);
```

```html
<li class = 'checkout-form__step checkout-form__step--active'>
  <span class="checkout-form__step-text p3"> Active</span>
</li>
```